# Is it a JMeter bug if ctx.getThreadNum() returns number starting from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing an issue while using the `ctx.getThreadNum()` inside JSR223 Post Processor.

From the JMeter API documentation of [getThreadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--), it shows:

```
the threadNum starting from one
```

But what I'm actually getting from the code is: returning the threadNum starting from ZERO

Seeing the attached image below:

[image: ctx.getThreadNum() returns starting from ZERO]

I even try to compare with the function `${__threadNum}`, and this function returns the number as expected (1) instead of `ctx.getThreadNum()` returns 0.

Could anyone please help to give me an advice if I'm doing something wrong? Or this is a bug from JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it's a [documentation bug](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--)

threadNum actually start with 0 and not as stated in documentation

I opened a bug [JMeterContext getThreadNum start at 0 and not 1](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63616)

It'll be fixed next JMeter version

Notice java indexes start with 0, so it is valid implementation, but I agree that at least documentation should be changed

Comment: I agree this should be a documentation bug. Thanks for your effort to logging this bug and hope to see it fixes in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, that's how it works, it is documented here:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum

But there was a javadoc bug that has been reported and is now fixed:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63616

So just add 1 to java code when comparing, but anyway never use ${} or a function ${__threadNum} inside JSR223 Groovy code, it will break caching of Compiled JSR223.

You can use rather the Parameters field to call the function ${__threadNum}

Comment: Hmm, I already read the description in the link you mentioned above. But can't say "it's not a bug". At least in the API documentation, it's not well documented. And actually, it says "starting from one". From my QA's perspective, it's a documented bug. By the way, using function inside the JSR223 Groovy code is just a way to compare the result between two cases. I know the best practice while working with caching of compiled JSR223. Anyway, thanks for your fast and detailed response.

Comment: you are right, there was a documentation bug that is now fixed in nightly version.